# How to calculate Hirshfeld charges from Gaussian?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, formal-charge

I am new to Gaussian and want to calculate Hirshfeld charges from Gaussian 09 or 16.

I found this input file for Methanol:

```
%nproc=8
%mem=1600mb
# mPW1PW91/6-311+G(2df,2p) pop=Hirshfeld scf=tight
Methanol
0 1
8 -0.046153000 -0.751257000 0.000000000
6 -0.046153000 0.658469000 0.000000000
1 0.857779000 -1.062372000 0.000000000
1 -1.086394000 0.976180000 0.000000000
1 0.437376000 1.072716000 0.889654000
1 0.437376000 1.072716000 -0.889654000
```

but when I run it I get this error:

```
QPErr --- A syntax error was detected in the input line.
 p) Pop=Hirshfeld scf=tight Methanol 0 1
                            '
 Last state= "GCL"
 TCursr=      3523 LCursr=        51
 Error termination via Lnk1e in /opt/software/gaussian/g09.e01/l1.exe at Wed Aug 19 01:02:31 2020.
 Job cpu time:       0 days  0 hours  0 minutes  0.6 seconds.
 File lengths (MBytes):  RWF=      5 Int=      0 D2E=      0 Chk=      1 Scr=
```

Any suggestion which part is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%nproc=8
%mem=1600mb
# mPW1PW91/6-311+G(2df,2p) pop=Hirshfeld scf=tight

Methanol

0 1
8 -0.046153000 -0.751257000 0.000000000
6 -0.046153000 0.658469000 0.000000000
1 0.857779000 -1.062372000 0.000000000
1 -1.086394000 0.976180000 0.000000000
1 0.437376000 1.072716000 0.889654000
1 0.437376000 1.072716000 -0.889654000
```

will do. All I did was to introduce blank lines after Route section (the one starting with `#`) and Title section (`Methanol`). Also, make sure that there is a blank line after the Molecule specification part. Gaussian is usually a convenient entry point to computational chemistry and you can find a lot of advice for it. The Gaussian manual is not bad, either. Have a look [at this](http://gaussian.com/input/) to get an impression about the syntax of input files - this is something Gaussian isn't forgiving about.